# SQL,JAVA Query to retrieve all columns based on Primary key

Tags: java, sql, oracle, select

I have a database table 1 as :

```
CustomerID  CustomerName    ContactName Address   City   PostalCode     Country
1(222)               tets           c          c      x        5456        xyd
2(222)               sas            w          q      w        2111        sas
```

I have a database table 2 as :

```
CustomerID  CustomerName    ContactName State    District    Ph Num       City
1               tets           c          c      x           5456        xyd
2               sas            w          q      w           2111        sas
```

I have to join both tables and get all the columns with primary key, where I have to remove (222) from table 1 and join. I am looking to use Java or SQL in Oracle.

Comment: Are both `CustomerId` columns `varchar`s?

Comment: yes both are varchars

Comment: And what [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: oracle , but  the solution can be in java or sql query

Answer (score 1):

You could use `instr` and `substr` to extract the part before the parenthesis from the `customerid` in the first table, and then just join the two:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM   t1
JOIN   t2 ON SUBSTR(t1.customerid, 0, INSTR(t1.customerid, '(')) = t2.customerid
```